# How do I get the color of a pixel at X,Y using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, colors, getpixel

Hey I am able to set the color of image via set Pixel Property but when i put condition getPixel then no error occurs but the programme stucks

### i put the code below please check it give me the solution :

```
    Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap("D:\test.bmp")

' Make Image Indexed

        Dim nii As New Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height,
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
        For y As Integer = 0 To nii.Height - 1
            For x = 0 To nii.Width - 1
                Dim cw As New Color
                cw = Color.Black
                If nii.GetPixel(x, y) = cw Then
                    nii.SetPixel(x, y, Red)
                End If

            Next
        Next
        PictureBox1.Image = FromFile("D:\test.bmp")
        PictureBox2.Image = nii
```

If i removed getPixel then programme works but full image color is going to be red.

Comment: do you mean `If nii.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb = cw.ToArgb`? you need to compare the `Argb` values when comparing color

Comment: Thanks for reply
I tried but it dosen't work !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compare the `ARGB` values of color

```
Dim cw As New Color
cw = Color.Black
dim curPixColor as Color = b.GetPixel(x, y)
If curPixColor.ToArgb = cw.ToArgb Then
    nii.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red)
End If
```

Or you should use the Equality Operator

```
Dim cw As New Color
cw = Color.Black
dim curPixColor as Color = b.GetPixel(x, y)
If Color.op_Equality(curPixColor, cw) Then
    nii.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red)
End If
```

Reference:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:
As you are getting pixel from a bmp there is no transparency supported. so your comparing color should be

```
cw = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0)
```

**Edit2**:
you are reading pixed from `nii` you should be reading from `b`

```
dim curPixColor as Color = b.GetPixel(x, y)
```

full code should be something like (tested)

```
    Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap("D:\test.bmp")

    ' Make Image Indexed

    Dim nii As New Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
    For y As Integer = 0 To nii.Height - 1
        For x = 0 To nii.Width - 1
            Dim cw As New Color
            cw = Color.Black
            Dim curPixColor As Color = b.GetPixel(x, y)
            If curPixColor.ToArgb() = cw.ToArgb() Then
                nii.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red)
            Else
                nii.SetPixel(x, y, curPixColor)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\test.bmp")
    PictureBox2.Image = nii
```

Comment: i tried it but it dosen't work again i tried both solution !! :(

Comment: no error message nothing i got it continued its process and when debug i seen that control does not enter in if condition when condition becomes true..

Comment: I see this in watch
curPixColor.ToArgb = 0 and cw.ToArgb = -16777216 how the value is assaign ??

Comment: hmm.. may be the color is not exact match. check the red, green and blue values. mainly check the alpha values.

Comment: i try this solution
If curPixColor.A = cw.A And curPixColor.R = cw.R And curPixColor.G = cw.G And curPixColor.B = cw.B Then
                    nii.SetPixel(x, y, Red)
                End If

but still same problem

Comment: i change it and i got my full image going to red not the selected part or black part 

this is image [RUN-TIME]
http://postimg.org/image/kerhjmztn/

Comment: Yes its Done Thanks For your help..!!

This is Change i made
i put nii instead of b so i solve it thanks for your help..!!

    Dim curPixColor As Color = b.GetPixel(x, y)
                    If curPixColor.ToArgb = cw.ToArgb Then
                        nii.SetPixel(x, y, Red)
                    End If

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but comparing the RGB values worked. Thanks!

In fact, instead of too many variables, you can just do:

```
If b.GetPixel(x,y).ToArgb() = Color.Black.ToArgb() then......
```

Comment: Answers are easier to read and more likely to be accepted if code examples are formatted.